# Nested IF in Gnu Mathprog

Tags: gnu, mathprog

I want to ask if it is possible to have **two nested if** in a GnuMathprog model and how i can write in the code something like that. For an example:

```
if a<>0
  a*x=y
 if b<>0
  b*c=d
else 0
else 0
;
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

First the bad news: GMPL does not support If-Then-Else statements.

But you can use conditionals in for-loops which can be nested. Here is a small working non-nested example:

```
for{a in {1..2}} {
   for {{0}: a == 1} {
      printf "First\n";
   } for {{0}: a != 1} {
      printf "Second\n";
   }
}
end;
```

This works fine while post-processing the model results/data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!